# Using JavaScript to add input text to an li, but only adding certain words

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I'm working on a menu project where customers input text, and it sends what they wrote into a separate ul in a separate div, sort of like a shopping cart menu.

Everything works fine, but I realized I can type anything I want into this div, including gibberish, and it will show up. I'd like to make an array of allowed words (ex: Pasta, Milk, Eggs, etc.), but I'm struggling to think of a way to write that. I was thinking of using an if statement but not sure exactly how I'd write it. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
function addLi() {
  let input    = document.getElementById("input").value;
  let listNode = document.getElementById("list");
  let liNode   = document.createElement("li");
  let txtNode  = document.createTextNode(input);
  liNode.appendChild(txtNode);
  listNode.appendChild(liNode);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-items">
  <h2>Added Items</h2>
  <ul id="list">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: an array of allowed words, and array includes method?

Comment: At this stage, why bother with allowing the user to type words. Just use a `<select>`, [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) or some other sort of autocomplete component

Comment: let allowedWords = ['Pasta', 'Milk', 'Eggs'];  If (allowedWords.includes(input)) { // append liNode into listNode };

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of allowed terms, and inside your function check whether the value entered is in that list:

```js
const whiteList = ['pasta', 'milk', 'apples'];

function addLi() {
  let input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  if (whiteList.includes(input.toLowerCase())) {
    const listNode = document.getElementById("list");
    const liNode = document.createElement("li");
    const txtNode = document.createTextNode(input);
    liNode.appendChild(txtNode);
    listNode.appendChild(liNode);
  }
}

document.getElementById('addItem').addEventListener('click', addLi);
```

```html
<div class="menu-items">
  <h2>Added Items</h2>
  <input type="text" id="input"> <button type="button" id="addItem">Add Item</button>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```